# Is Lusztig's conjecture solved?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request

What I said is Lusztig's conjecture about representation of quantum group at root of unity and representation of Lie algebra at positive characters.

It seems that Andersen-Jantzen-Soergel ever wrote a book on this conjecture.

Is it solved? Any recent development? I am looking for reference talking about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of that book is that the conjecture is true for sufficiently large, but unspecified characteristic. (First fix a Dynkin type.)
More recently Peter Fiebig has given actual bounds. See

An upper bound on the exceptional characteristics for Lusztig's character formula
by Peter Fiebig arXiv:0811.1674v2 at http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1674v2

Comment: To expand Wilberd's comment, the ongoing work of R. Bezrukavnikov
and I. Mirkovic (following up their joint work with D. Rumynin)
takes a more geometric viewpoint.   This preprint, now in version 3,
addresses the closely related conjectures of Lusztig in 1997-99 on
bases in equivariant K-theory:

    http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1001.2562   

As in AJS, applications to characteristic `$p$` are (so far) dependent on `$p$` being "large enough".   But the conjectures go beyond restricted Lie algebra representations to those attached to arbitrary nilpotent orbits.



Comment: A little more detail about [AJS], which is a 300+ page paper 
(Asterisque 220, 1994) but has a readable introduction.   They
work in a graded setting with Lie algebra modules, getting for large enough `$p$` and suitably bounded weights a precise comparison with the quantum enveloping algebra of Lusztig at a `$p$`th root of unity.  In the latter case, one combines work of Kashiwara-Tanisaki on the analogue of the Kazhdan-Lusztig Conjecture for affine Lie algebras with work of K-L passing from there to quantum groups.
[AJS] relies more on combinatorics than on geometry.

Comment: Update: This final version of a survey article by Peter Fiebig is an updated version of the last v4 posted on arXiv and is now freely available in PDF format from Bull. London Math. Soc.: blms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/

Answer (score 20):

Geordie Williamson has found counterexamples to Lusztig's conjecture: 
http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/geordie/Torsion.pdf

Apparently, any bound on the largest prime that breaks Lusztig's conjecture must be at least proportional to $n\log n$, and this is probably still far too optimistic; I think it's now believed that you'll need an exponential bound.